# Shorthand for deleting the remote branch in git?

Tags: git

Is there a shorthand for deleting the remote branch in git?

I am currently doing:

```
git push origin :long-branch-name
```

Comment: You mean deleting remote branch? Is the only problem a long name? Doesn’t Tab-completion suffice?

Comment: Yes. Tab completion does not work on my machine. I am on Windows (sorry) and using git bash. Any information on how to enable it gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Well, I’m on Windows too and Tab completion works for me in Git Bash (not in cmd.exe). Just tried it with a remote branch name before posting my first comment…

Comment: well, you won't shortcut the `long-branch-name`. In general you also need to specify origin, so the best you could probably do is alias `push origin`? Don't think it would be easy to put a colon without space into an alias though.